# Boost Subgraph Copy Constructor not working with Qt 5.0.2 and MinGW

Tags: c++, windows, qt, boost

I was using Qt 4.8 and minGW compiler with boost 1.46.0 for my project but now i have moved to Qt 5.0.2 and MinGW compiler with Boost 1.55.0, But the copy constructor for subgraph is not working well. It is not adding vertices to subgraph (Shows 0 items in vertex list if performed debug).

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list< boost::listS,
boost::vecS,
boost::bidirectionalS,
boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, int ,
   property<vertex_position_t, point, VertexProperties> > ,
boost::property<boost::edge_index_t,int , EdgeProperties>,
boost::property<graph_custom_prop_t,GraphProperties> >
Graph;
typedef boost::subgraph< Graph > SubGraph;
```

I am taking input into gMainGraph and I need to copy it to m_gMainGraph

```
SubGraph* m_gMainGraph;
m_gMainGraph = new SubGraph(gMainGraph);
```

Subgraphs are getting created but the vertices and edges within subgraphs are not getting created and are getting added only to the top most parent graph.
Here in above code gMainGraph is not getting deep copied to m_gMainGraph.

Answer (score 0):

This is some work around for this problem as subgraph copy constructor is not implemented to perform deep copy in boost 1_55_0.
I have tried updating boost subgraph copy constuctor. Just use following code in your boost's subgraph.hpp file. You need to comment some code from 1.52.0 and use following changes.

```
// copy constructor
/*Updated the copy constructor to work properly
    As it's working in 1.46.0 and not in 1.52.0, In 1.52.0, the subgraph constructor  is not itrating the child of child subgraphs
    So only the direct children of main subgraph was getting copied*/
subgraph(const subgraph& x)
    : m_graph(x.m_graph), m_parent(x.m_parent), m_edge_counter(x.m_edge_counter)   //Added m_graph(x.m_graph)
    , m_global_vertex(x.m_global_vertex), m_global_edge(x.m_global_edge)
{
    // This loop belongs to 1.46.0
    for(typename ChildrenList::const_iterator i = x.m_children.begin();
        i != x.m_children.end(); ++i)
    {
        m_children.push_back(new subgraph<Graph>( **i ));
    }
    /* 1.52.0 code*/

    //        if(x.is_root())
    //        {
    //         m_graph = x.m_graph;
    //        }
    //        // Do a deep copy (recursive).
    //        // Only the root graph is copied, the subgraphs contain
    //        // only references to the global vertices they own.
    //        typename subgraph<Graph>::children_iterator i,i_end;
    //        boost::tie(i,i_end) = x.children();
    //        for(; i != i_end; ++i)
    //        {
    //         subgraph<Graph> child = this->create_subgraph();
    //         child = *i;
    //         vertex_iterator vi,vi_end;
    //         boost::tie(vi,vi_end) = vertices(*i);
    //         for (;vi!=vi_end;++vi)
    //         {
    //          add_vertex(*vi,child);
    //         }
    //       }
}
```